# bash to automate input file daily + ping test

Tags: bash

I'm running a ping test for 100 IP's daily, every day the input file  IP will get updated becauses its dynamic. And I'm specifying input(100 IP list) as first argument. As the below script will ran for every 10 mins

Note:- I'm using different IP's everyday, so need to change the input file every day at 12AM

Running script as background at Apr 1 at 12AM

```
sh ping.sh IPlist_apr1.txt &
```

on second day my secondary script(which will create updated IP's) will choose other set of IP's in this file format 'IPlist_apr2.txt' 
On third day - IPlist_apr3.txt ... and it will log $1.log every day on the CWD.

likewise this process continue, What I'm actually looking my ping script should handle the list day by day as first argument.

Snippet of my actual script.

```
t=10m                         
ip=$1                     #### specify the file having IP's
while sleep $t
do
    if ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "`date +%H:%M`: $ip is up";
    else
        echo "`date +%H:%M`: $ip is down"; 
    fi >>$1.log;
done
```

Comment: if your intention is to use `bash` why calling the script with `sh`?

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to *read* the IP addresses from the file named by the argument.

```
  while IFS= read -r ipaddr; do
    if ping -c1 "$ipaddr"; then
      status=up
    else
      status=down
    fi
    printf '%s: %s is %s\n' "$(date +%H:%M)" "$ipaddr" "$status"
  done < "$1"
```

Note that this runs one batch of pings, then exits. The caller should be responsible for sleeping 10 minutes and specifying the correct file name for the input.

Comment: this is not I'm looking here the input will comes as first argument and the script should choose automatically new files created by other script and process that file as input as first argument for the second day.

Comment: In short , I'm starting script manually 
#./ping.sh IPlist_apr1.txt &  { first day }   #./ping.sh IPlist_apr2.txt & {second day } likewsie this process goes on ....